# Node.js dns.lookup() to internal docker-compose service

Tags: node.js, docker, kubernetes, docker-compose, dns

I've try yo measure DNS latency in my docker-compose/kubernetes cluster.

```
  setInterval(() => {
    console.time('dns-test');

    dns.lookup('http://my-service', (_, addresses, __) => {
      console.log('addresses:', addresses);
      console.timeEnd('dns-test');
    });
  }, 5000);
```

But get `addresses: undefined`, any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`...dns.lookup('http://my-service'...`

The [lookup](https://nodejs.org/api/dns.html#dnslookuphostname-options-callback) function (with example usage) takes the first parameter as the host name that you want to lookup, eg. google.com. You should remove "http://" from the name you passed in.

Comment: OMG, thx you a lot :)